# I want to make the first column static and have it sortable?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is my code so far pretty simple design, I just don't know how to get the first column fixed or have it sortable

The end goal is to have it imported into Muse

https://jsfiddle.net/clykins/o4qap6j8/

```
<style type="text/css">
<div style="float:left; width: 150px">
   Navigation Code Here
</div>
<div style="float: left">
   Other Content Here
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse;}
.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#acc8cc;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;text-align:left;}
.tftable tr {background-color:#d4e3e5;}
.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;}
.tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
</style>

<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>Header 4</th><th>Header 5</th>
  <th>6</th>
  <th>7</th>
  <th>8</th>
  <th>9</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:1 Cell:1</td><td>Row:1 Cell:2</td><td>Row:1 Cell:3</td><td>Row:1 Cell:4</td><td>Row:1 Cell:5</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>400000</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:2 Cell:1</td><td>Row:2 Cell:2</td><td>Row:2 Cell:3</td><td>Row:2 Cell:4</td><td>Row:2 Cell:5</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7000000</td>
  <td>800000</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:3 Cell:1</td><td>Row:3 Cell:2</td><td>Row:3 Cell:3</td><td>Row:3 Cell:4</td><td>Row:3 Cell:5</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:4 Cell:1</td><td>Row:4 Cell:2</td><td>Row:4 Cell:3</td><td>Row:4 Cell:4</td><td>Row:4 Cell:5</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14000000</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:5 Cell:1</td><td>Row:5 Cell:2</td><td>Row:5 Cell:3</td><td>Row:5 Cell:4</td><td>Row:5 Cell:5</td>
  <td>1700000000</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td><td>Row:6 Cell:2</td><td>Row:6 Cell:3</td><td>Row:6 Cell:4</td><td>Row:6 Cell:5</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td><td>Row:6 Cell:2</td><td>Row:6 Cell:3</td><td>Row:6 Cell:4</td><td>Row:6 Cell:5</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td><td>Row:6 Cell:2</td><td>Row:6 Cell:3</td><td>Row:6 Cell:4</td><td>Row:6 Cell:5</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td><td>Row:6 Cell:2</td><td>Row:6 Cell:3</td><td>Row:6 Cell:4</td><td>Row:6 Cell:5</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>


</div>
```

Please help

Comment: For advanced tables I have had great success with the dataTables plugin for query

Comment: I am not to familiar with that language, i wish i was though.

Comment: sorry I meant jquery

Answer (score 0):

To make it scrollable, you can use jQuery.

I haven't found an exact solution for your scenario.  However, below is a link to making the header not scroll.

[Similar problem with solution][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/
```

Comment: Do you know a way i can switch that to fix the column instead of the row?